# Firebase authentication in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set up Firebase Authentication for a login after setting up everything correctly I am running into an error in the dart file i created.

1- Undefined class 'FirebaseUser'
2.A value of type 'User' can't be returned from the method 'registerWithEmailAndPassword' because it has a return type of 'Future

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class User {
  final String uid;

  User({required this.uid});
}

class AuthBase{

  User _userFromFireBase (FirebaseUser user){
    return User(uid: user.uid);
  }

  Future<void> registerWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    final  authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    return _userFromFireBase(authResult.user);
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your error message may have been cut off. Could you please ensure that you include the entire error message?

Comment: Try replacing Future<void>  with  Future<User>

Comment: 1.Undefined class 'FirebaseUser'. (Documentation)  Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'FirebaseUser'

Comment: I think it is not `FirebaseUser` in the latest version but `User`. Therefore you need to rename your own `User` class and use `User` for the Firebase user.